# Thread falls without coredump

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, ubuntu, debugging

I have multi-thread application, in which main thread falls on some event. Thread falls on SIGSEGV signal. Other threads continue work. My question is how to dig maximum information about  failed thread to analyse it later? Starting with the question of how to find out which of the threads fell.
Really it is actual ussie which arose when working with qt 4.7 signal/slot system + webview widget. It's interesting that on version 5 everything is fine.
I will be happy for any idea. I'm working on ubuntu, qt project.

Comment: On Windows I would attach a debugger and let it be signalled when a thread terminates. In WInDbg it is `sxe et`. To analyze it later, I would create a crash dump with `.dump`. I'm sure all that exists in GDB as well.

Comment: Shouldn't your debugger immediately break when `SIGSEGV` is generated? You may want to check gdb signal handling settings.

Comment: Yes it is good idea to break process after SIGSEGV. I have ability to run/attach gdb on my program. What do you mean talking about signal handling settings?

Comment: So you didn't run program under debugger yet? Then you should definitely do so. You can read about signal handling settings [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html).

Comment: Useful tools are: `gdb`, `valgrind` and `rr`.